# Go back button in review step gets misplaced by PayPal smart payment buttons

Tags: commerce

I'm using Drupal 10.1 with Commerce 2.36 and a custom checkout flow with the multistep checkout flow plugin. I added Paypal checkout later. On the order information step the *"Continue to review"* button is rendered inside `div.layout-region-checkout-footer` and thus gets a bottom margin. But on the review step the *"Go back"* button/link is rendered after the `div.paypal-buttons-container` inside the `div.layout-checkout-form` instead and thus has no bottom margin. This produces some really ugly UI as it directly sticks to the page footer which has a different background.

The *"Go back"* button is created as suffix of the next action instead of being an own action, which looks really strange to me. And the `commerce_paypal` module assign it as suffix of it's smart payment buttons form element (causing the misplacement).

How can I place the *"Go back"* on all steps where it shows inside the `div.layout-region-checkout-footer` like the next action buttons?

Comment: In Drupal, you have a lot of templates, and all of these templates have a suggestion.
In those templates, you can manage your design easily. I suggest you this documentation [Working With Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/working-with-twig-templates)